# R: how to compute the distance between the columns of a matrix?

Tags: r

The R function `dist` "computes and returns the distance matrix computed by using the specified distance measure to compute the distances between the rows of a data matrix".

However, I want the distance measure to be computed between the *columns* of a data matrix, not the rows! How can I do that?

Do I need to rotate the matrix. If so, how? If not, should I use a different function?

Comment: Transpose before `dist`? `trmtx <- t(mtx)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can use R function `t`?
`t(x)` will transpose matrix `x`.